# Difference between valid names in JSON and JavaScript object literals

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON-formatted document like so:

```
{
    "the-field": "something",
    // etc
}
```

When I call `foo = JSON.parse()` it spits out an object literal with a field `foo.the-field`, but when I try `console.log(foo.the-field)` I'm told that it's not proper formatting for a JavaScript variable. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) here

```
foo["the-field"]
```

From Docs

If you are using dot notation then

> property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of
>   alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and
>   dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example,
>   object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

Comment: Formatting tip: the backticks go inside the brackets :)